# Get The Label Value of a Gridview by Clicking a Button uing Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have this ASP Gridview with label Description and a Button Edit and my Problem is that I can't get the ID of the label on button click using JQuery. How can I make this possible?

Here's HTML my code

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdAssetInventory" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decription">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Description")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="grdEdit" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
</ItemTemplate>
</ItemTemplateField>                    
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

MY JQuery code

```
function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;                                                          
        alert("RowIndex: " + rowIndex);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ClientIDMode property of the label - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

You probably want to change it to Predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using javascript. If you actually using JQuery. This works for me:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="idField"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="buttonField"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.each($(".buttonField"), function(index, btn) {
            $(btn).on('click', function (e) {
                alert("Row clicked " + $("table tr").index($(this).closest("tr"))
                    + ", Id " + $(this).parent("td").siblings("td.idField").text().trim());
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that I give the names **idField** and **buttonField** for easier traverse.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for the party, but i struggled to find the solution myself and i hope this may help any one got struggled like i did. 
Here's a solution found in another question: [How to Get TextBox value from button click in Nested Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413228/how-to-get-textbox-value-from-button-click-in-nested-gridview?rq=1)
.In the answer provided by ConnorsFan, it is clear the method he used to find a certain control using the following code in jquery

1.)In asp.net html part of the item template of the gridview:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="showText(this); return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

2.) jquery code

```
 function showText(btn) {
alert($(btn).closest('div').find('input[type=text]').val());
}
```

## Remark:

The gridview is represented in html as a table of rows and table data cells so instead of searching for a div i searched for the table row or 'tr'
I created a hidden field and assigned a value to it in the gridview_rowdatabound() to be able to distinguish between different types and the code ended up to be:

```
  var i = $(btn).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val();
  alert('subscribed to ' + i );
```