# How to Get TextBox value from button click in Nested Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Nested Gridview having `textbox & Button` column. How to display value of `textbox` in alert when `Button Click` by using jquery in asp.net.
For Example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridParent" runat="server">
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
         <td>
           -----------
           -----------
         </td>
         <td>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridChild" runat="server">
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Textbox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick=showText(); return false; />
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

JQuery which i'm using

```
function showText() {            
            var text= $("#TextBox1").val();
            alert(text);
            return false;
        }
```

i found a exact question in stackoverflow but my question is little different because i want to get textbox value in nested gridview by using JQuery not with C# Coding

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` add `clientIDMode` like this:

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
```

Then:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Button1").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert($("#TextBox1").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your jQuery loaded ?

Comment: Okey try the updated answer put the above code somewhere in your page ;)

Comment: Getting Error Compilation Error

Comment: @Ismali : Again Same Error Compilation Error

Comment: Are you using ASP.net prior to 4.0 !

Comment: Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="showText(this); return false;" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

with the following `showText` function, which looks for a text box in the same table cell as the button that was clicked:

```
function showText(btn) {
    alert($(btn).closest('td').find('input[type=text]').val());
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414070/add-value-to-textbox-in-nested-gridview-by-using-jquery/38414182?noredirect=1#comment64236564_38414182), the text box and the button could be inside of a div container. If that is the case, the function `showText` should be:

```
function showText(btn) {
    alert($(btn).closest('div').find('input[type=text]').val());
}
```