# Add Value to TextBox in Nested GridView by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Nested Gridview having `a link`  is used to show and hide div tag in nested gridview.
 By default this `Div Tag` is disable when we click on `a link` to show(enable) `Div` tag under this `Div Tag` they is one  `TextBox` and one `Button`.
When user click `a link` div will be enable at the same time i want to add `@username` in this textbox

For Example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridParent" runat="server">
 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
         <td>
           -----------
           -----------
         </td>
         <td>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridChild" runat="server">
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <a href='#' onclick='showDiv(); return false;'>ShowDiv</a>
               <div id='divShow'>
                 <asp:Textbox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick=showText(); return false; />
               </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

JQuery which i'm using

```
function showDiv() {            
         $("#divShow").show();
         $("#TextBox1").text('@username');
         return false;
        }
```

the above jquery code working to Enable Div Tag but not adding `@username` to `TextBox1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ASP, but if this is rendering the textbox in the webpage similar to `<input type='text' />` then you want to use $("#TextBox1").val('@username') rather than .text()

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite similar to the one I gave to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413228/how-to-get-textbox-value-from-button-click-in-nested-gridview). You can pass a reference to the anchor tag in the call to `showDiv` (using the `this` keyword) and set the class name of the div (e.g. `innerDiv`):

```
<a href='#' onclick='showDiv(this); return false;'>ShowDiv</a>
<div id='divShow' class='innerDiv'>
```

The `showDiv` could find the table cell container, then the element with the `innerDiv` class name and the text box.

```
function showDiv(lnk) {
    var $div = $(lnk).closest('td').find('.innerDiv');
    $div.show();
    $div.find('input[type=text]').val('@username');
}
```

Please note that I use class names and element types in the jQuery selectors. The ID of the elements are not reliable since each row of the GridView displays these controls, which should all have a different ID.

Comment: its working for Div Hide and Show but `@username` is not adding to textbox

Comment: I modified the `showDiv` function to search the text box inside of the div.

Comment: Try testing without the `onclick` event on your button (which is incorrect, according to the code sample posted in your question). When I test this answer with your markup and the changes that I suggest, I see the div and the text is set to `@username`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan asp.net does not add `type="text"` while rendering textbox controls.

Comment: @lorond - From what I can see when I inspect the HTML of the page, it does add `type="text"`. I tested on IE, Firefox and Chrome and this solution works in those three browsers.

Comment: @ConnorsFan oh, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code.

First, ASP.NET generates complex IDs for server controls (something like `blabla_gridparent_gridchild_textbox1_blabla`, instead of simple `textbox1`), so if you want to work with you control on client side, you have to ask ASP.NET for that ID via [`ClientID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your server control:

```
function showDiv() {            
     $("#divShow").show();
     $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val('@username');
     return false;
}
```

Note, this is a server code. I assume this JS code placed into your `.aspx` page (or `.ascx` control), not in static `.js` file. In case of static `.js` file you need to pass that ID as parameter.

Second, you have to use [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) jquery method to work with `input` value. [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is rendered into `input`.